# Parameterise ADF Activity timeout in ARM template parameters definiton file?

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I need to parameterise the timeout value for a particular SQL Server Stored Procedure activity and a Copy activity within Azure Data Factory using the ARM Template Parameters Definition file, so the values can be specified during deployment to another environment.

How do I structure the JSON correctly in order to be able to do this? I've tried following the guidance in the Microsoft article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/2018-06-01/factories/pipelines?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) but it doesnt parameterise them.

I've tried it as per the below and a number of variations of this (with the below example being for the stored procedure activity):

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines": {
    "properties": {
        "activities": {
            "name": "ActivityName",
            "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "="
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

To parameterize the timeout property for SQL stored procedure or a copy activity, you need to define a user defined parameter called `storedProcedureTimeout` under `parameters` block. Once it is defined, reference it in the `activity properties` as detailed below.

Referring to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-resource-manager-template), for deploying a data factory containing datasets and pipeline activities including your specific requirement for parameterizing timeout values. The deployment process was successful as shown below.

```bash
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "dataFactoryName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[format('datafactory{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Data Factory Name"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location"
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[format('storage{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "storage account"
      }
    },
    "blobContainerName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[format('blob{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "blob container"
      }
    },
    "storedProcedureTimeout": {
       "type": "string",
       "defaultValue": "00:10:00"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "dataFactoryLinkedServiceName": "ArmtemplateStorageLinkedService",
    "dataFactoryDataSetInName": "ArmtemplateTestDatasetIn",
    "dataFactoryDataSetOutName": "ArmtemplateTestDatasetOut",
    "pipelineName": "ArmtemplateSampleCopyPipeline"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryLinkedServiceName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
          "connectionString": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2021-08-01').keys[0].value)]"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('dataFactoryName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryDataSetInName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
          "referenceName": "[variables('dataFactoryLinkedServiceName')]",
          "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "Binary",
        "typeProperties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
            "container": "[parameters('blobContainerName')]",
            "folderPath": "input",
            "fileName": "emp.txt"
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('dataFactoryName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryLinkedServiceName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryDataSetOutName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
          "referenceName": "[variables('dataFactoryLinkedServiceName')]",
          "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "Binary",
        "typeProperties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
            "container": "[parameters('blobContainerName')]",
            "folderPath": "output"
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('dataFactoryName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryLinkedServiceName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('pipelineName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "activities": [
        {
          "name": "ActivityName",
            "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "[parameters('storedProcedureTimeout')]"
            }
            },
          {
            "name": "MyCopyActivity",
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
              "source": {
                "type": "BinarySource",
                "storeSettings": {
                  "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                  "recursive": true
                }
              },
              "sink": {
                "type": "BinarySink",
                "storeSettings": {
                  "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                }
              },
              "enableStaging": false
            },
            "inputs": [
              {
                "referenceName": "[variables('dataFactoryDataSetInName')]",
                "type": "DatasetReference"
              }
            ],
            "outputs": [
              {
                "referenceName": "[variables('dataFactoryDataSetOutName')]",
                "type": "DatasetReference"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('dataFactoryName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryDataSetInName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets', parameters('dataFactoryName'), variables('dataFactoryDataSetOutName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

***Deployment succeded:***

[image]

[image]

*Note*: If you need timeout to be applied for other copy related activities, follow the same procedure as above.